# preg_replace_callback create_function is deprecated

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

i have the following function for replace variables in a string

```
function replace_variables($string,$variables)
{


        return preg_replace_callback('/{\$([A-Za-z_]+)\}/', 
           create_function ('$matches', 'return $$variables[1];'), $string);
}
```

In php 7.2 create_function is deprecated and i dont know how to rewrite the function to work with php 5.2

Thanks

Comment: `function($matches) use ($variables){ return $$variables[1]; }`  Use a closure.  Not sure about the `$$` though (variable variable).  Seems pointless in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function replace_variables($string,$variables)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/{\$([A-Za-z_]+)\}/',
        function ($matches) use ($variables) {
            return $$variables[1];
        }, $string);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply